# Is there a way to show file in working tree by Git?

Tags: git

I know `git show HEAD:<file>` shows file content of HEAD revision, and `git show :<file>` shows file content of INDEX, but I can't show file content of working tree using git.

Like `less <file>`, it can be achieved very easy by other commands, but I want to do this only using git commands.

Comment: `git config alias.cat '!cat'`, then `git cat FILE`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.  Most Git commands operate on what is in the repository itself, and the version in the work tree is not in the repository.

You could, of course, `git add` the work-tree version so that it is now in the repository via the index, but that would—at least potentially—overwrite a version that exists only as an index entry, e.g., from `git add -p`.  (This actually leaves an unreferenced blob in the repository proper, so if you have the hash and the blob has not been garbage-collected, you *can* still retrieve that file, but this is well into "crazy" territory. :-) )